# Magento 1.9.3.1 Upgrade Error

Tags: magento

I have upgraded Magento to 1.9.3.1 from 1.9.1.1 from magento connect manager and after successful up-gradation I got this error:

> *Exception during cache and session cleaning*

When I access my site I got this error:

> You have been blocked from accessing this site. If you feel this is a
>   mistake please email abuse@securedserverspace.com

Which is I think is not a Magento error but more of a server error anyways whatever it is how do I fix it? Please help.

Comment: Follow the instructions, and email the hosting company. This is not a code problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem with the hosting company, and you should contact them for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
**You have to consult with hosting provider.**

Case 2: **you have doubt regarding code then you can update via following method.**
Update to Magento 1.9.3.1 - Via FTP -

1) Enable Maintenance Mode by creating a file in root magento folder called maintenance.flag

2) For admin (you) to have access to the frontpage while you perform upgrade (check everything as it should be)
Find this

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
```

Add following to line 49 and 50

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('Your Ip Address');
```

Where the ip-address is your IP.   Replace line 59 should be

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
```

With

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
```

3) Disable Compiling and also disable cache. Remember to flush cache.

4) Unpack the Magento 1.9.3.1 files on your computer and upload them to your root.

5) Refresh your webpage when the files are uploaded. You can see in Admin section that the magento 
has been updated.

NB! Remember to check for upgrades for your third party modules / themes if you have this. This will only upgrade magento. 
Also a good idea before uploading the files is to delete the error_log in your root folder and logs under var/log. This way you can see what errors may occur when you have done the proceeding.